Can I calculate the number of Cloudy pixels in a clipped ROI in GEE for an entire ImageCollection
cloudy pixel editing
I have tried a number of approaches by creating cloud masks for Landsat in GEE.
Basically, what I am trying to do is insert a polygon as my ROI; it is a lake. Then, within that polygon, calculate the NDWI and NDVI to assess changes in water level over time.
Since the lake is fairly small compared to an entire Landsat Image it would be easier for me to filter my image collection based on the number of cloudy pixels within the ROI (lake area). That way, I would not have to only use images that have 'less than 10%' as that greatly reduces the number of images I can use, especially in the Arctic, where it is very cloudy.
Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? I will try and add some code if I figure anything out. Thanks!
